# Java assert operation is safe

Tags: java, junit

I am looking for something like this:

```
assertSafe(Integer.parseInt(val))
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? side-effects free?

Comment: Why not just a try/catch?

Comment: @morgano I mean no exception would be raised!

Comment: @John Was thinking of an easier way! but seems eventually i have to.

Comment: @ORCL Until lambda expressions are supported by Java, a try/catch is probably your best bet

Comment: @John I mostly need it for type conversion from String to Integer. I am thinking of maybe there is a better way of doing the type checking compared to custom code. This is very common - i.e. type checking, for example, when extracting values from JSON strings - and I wonder why it is not readily available. But anyway thanks for your comment!

Comment: I don't get why you want to do this.  If you are writing a for that method and you don't expect it to throw any exception in such situation, you can simply leave it as is.  In case there is exception thrown, Junit will report to you that the test case failed because of unexpected exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want assertSafe to catch any Exception, and fail, right? Unfortunately this is not possible with Java (at least today). Generally speaking, all parameters must always be evaluated before they are passed to a method.

You could create a helper method though:

```
public static void assertSafeInt(String val) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(val);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(val + " is not an int");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
assertSafeInt(val);
```

Not as general as you would want I guess? Java 8 with lambdas might help a bit, but I don't think the syntax will be as clean as you'd like.

Scala has something called "call by name" which is really passing a code block as a function. It is easy to create assertSafe in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

> type checking, for example, when extracting values from JSON strings - and I wonder why it is not readily available.

If you use Scanner it support this with hasNextInt(), hasNextDouble() or just hasNext() => String.

Normally you know what type to expect and if you don't you parse this as you read it.  I would avoid reading a String something I would want as an `int` and this is inefficient. ;)